# Why does Firefox 51 fail on inspector compare nodes?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

My plugin that works for comparing DOM nodes in Firefox 50, doesn't seem to work on Firefox 51 beta. Right click, select node A in inspector, right click, select node B in inspector, and it gives an odd error... Odd because the file does exist, as you can see:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Which version *exactly* are you using? e.g. 51.0a2, 51.0b1 (beta),  51.0b1 (beta-unbranded), etc.? In addition, how have you loaded your add-on (temporary, normal-signed, normal-unsigned)

Comment: "51.0b1 (64-bit)" - I have it installed via folder as in earlier versions.

Comment: So, unbranded Firefox? Correct?

Comment: @Makyen You mean where I downloaded it from? https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next

Comment: Why not the [official download channel](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/)? Or from the [releases directory](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/51.0b1/)?

Comment: You have what is, probably, effectively an unbranded version.  I have experienced various issues with testing add-ons on unbranded beta builds that do not appear on the same version of Firefox when it was in the Developer Edition, nor once it reaches release. In general, I take testing on these builds with a considerable grain of salt (i.e. i don't trust testing on them).

Comment: @Makyen Why? Going through the link to the PPA maintainer, "Mozilla Team", suggests that this is the team that packages the official Ubuntu Firefox.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MozillaTeam